# How can I make it so my browser never tries to reintpret localhost as www.localhost.com?

Tags: url, firefox

I'm working with Firefox, but I'm sure answers for all browsers could be useful.  When my browser can't find localhost:8000, it tries www.localhost.com:8000.  I don't want it to ever do that because then I have to retype localhost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `about:config` in the browser bar.

Type `browser.fixup.alternate.enabled` in the search box that appears.

Right click on the `browser.fixup.alternate.enabled` that appears in the filtered list below and choose `Toggle` to set the value to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own quesiton, I found a solution to the problem.  You can simply set your hosts file to redirect www.localhost.com to 127.0.0.1.  On Mac the hosts file is /etc/hosts.  There is a similar file for Windows, and probably Unix/Linux as well.  You can add this line to the file:

127.0.0.1 www.localhost.com